# Special Characters in Markdown - Pandoc and Github Flavored

Tags: pdf, latex, special-characters, markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to use "greater than or equal to" and "less than or equal to" symbols in a document that I'm producing in Markdown. I'm striving to have this document render correctly to a PDF via Pandoc and on GitHub, via Github flavored Markdown. However, I can't find a solution to produce these symbols that works in both interpretations of Markdown

The regular symbols (≥ and  ≤) show-up fine in Git Flavored Markdown, as do HTML-style special characters. However, when I try to run that to get a PDF via Pandoc, I get this error:

```
pandoc test.md -o test.pdf
pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:≤ not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.120 ≤

Try running pandoc with --latex-engine=xelatex.
```

I've used the xelatex engine, and it simply doesn't produce a character in that place.

Latex-style special characters (e.g., $\geq$) render fine to a PDF via Pandoc but are not interpreted by Git Flavored Markdown.

Are there any suggestions for using special characters that work with Github flavored Markdown and Pandoc/Latex? Or is there a way to indicate to Pandoc/LaTeX that it needs to interpret HTML-formatted special characters or something?

Comment: This is a font issue - the default font doesn't have the glyph for ≤. Try running pandoc with the option `--variable mainfont=Georgia`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default LaTeX engine (pdflatex) doesn't play well with unicode. So using XeLaTeX is a good idea, but as @MatthewPickering mentioned, the font also needs to have a glyph for ≤, so switching the font to one that does solves the issue:

```
$ echo "≤" | pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -o test.pdf --variable mainfont=Georgia
```

Comment: Thanks @mb21. When I run the exact line you suggest I get this error:
! Undefined control sequence.
\fontspec_calc_scale:n ...ec_tmpb_dim }\fp_div:Nn
                                                  \l_fontspec_tmpa_fp {\l_fo...
l.18     \setmainfont{Georgia}

Any thoughts? I'm running Pandoc 1.13.1 and using MiKTeX on Windows 7 if that helps

Comment: I'm not familiar with MiKTeX (tested the above on Mac), but you'll have to make sure the font is installed for MiKTeX. Maybe install the `winfonts` package with the Miktex Package Manager?

Comment: Okay - I've got it working now; I had tried to install winfonts - that didn't seem to work (or I didn't install correctly?). Then just updated all of my MikTex packages (with winfonts still not listed in the Package Manager), and it works exactly as listed above.

Comment: I was receiving a similar error message and fixed it by updating to the latest version of fontspec.